# Apply jQuery function append on seleced tab

Tags: jquery, html

On a page I have some fields and tabs. I used bootstrap tabs and each tab should have some particular fields in the common part of the page. I used function append like this so that i can i add them :

```
var add  = $(".add_fields");
$(add).click(function(e){ 
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="f2" id="field2"  
class="form-control col-xs-5 " /> </div> '); });
```

at the second tab i add the class "add_fields":

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane " id="tab1">  ... </div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane .add_fields " id="tab2">  ...</div>
```

but the content is not displayed ?

Can anybody tell me how to append some field or just some text automatically when a tab is selected?

Comment: again ID must be unique. You can not duplicate it in one page

Comment: wrapper is defined like this : var wrapper  = $(".input_fields_wrap");
<div class="input_fields_wrap col-xs-5"> .... </div> @callback

Comment: Shouldn't you use the class selector instead of only **wrap**? `$('.input_fields_wrap').append(..)` instead of `$(wrap)`

Comment: @daremachine i edited it, in original code i have different identifiers.

Comment: @mk117 i think is the same think as i explained what 'wraper' do, but still it doesn't work?

Comment: to show only some simple text , try add custom attr in tab div. `<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane " id="tab1" data-stext="some text">` and then in wrapper container div, add it. something like this : `$(".wrapper").append($(this).attr("data-stext"));`

Comment: You could post a jsfiddle for your question, that way resolving it would be easier...

Answer (score 2):

First, check that your selector is correct. (you can use simple console.log() or alert() in click function).

- change your selector to $(document).on("click", ".add_fields", function(){});
- create a certain wrapper tag (like `div` or `section`) to append the inputs in, and set id for it.
- for getting additional info from tabs, you can set custom attribute (`data-attr="some"`).
- check your assigns id to tags to avoid duplicated in page.

and always check your debugger console for warnings and errors.